# ROR - Unable to create a new directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, rubygems

(side note: my mac crashed a couple of weeks ago due to some os problem; the apple people at the store took care of it, and it's back to "normal" - just stating this in case it's related to the current problem)

today, i decided to practice some ruby after having not done it in a while (following hartl's tutorial)

when trying to generate a new application, after a pause and seemingly normal files, it comes up with this: (for the record - when I created my previous directories - I never had a problem with it until today)

```
 Installing json (1.7.5) with native extensions 
 Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/name_withheld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
 creating Makefile

 make
 sh: make: command not found


 Gem files will remain installed in /Users/name_withheld/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/json-1.7.5     for   inspection.
  Results logged to /Users/name_withheld/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator    /gem_make.out
  An error occured while installing json (1.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
 Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Tried to install json. This is what it comes up with:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/name_withheld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
sh: make: command not found


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/name_withheld/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/json-1.7.5 for     inspection.
Results logged to /Users/name_withheld/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator    /gem_make.out
```

Anyway, it seems the problem may be related to gcc? or xcode?

I'm confused, and I never had a problem until today! Hence why I think it may be do something with the reset that the people at apple store may have done, maybe?

For the record, when I try to download command line for xcode which everyone says it's free, it's not. You have to register and pay some sort of licensing fee.

Help? Can anyone sort out my confusion on what I should do here?

**Edit**
Am on 10.6.8 version (ie Snow Leopard?)

**Edit 2**
Have added this to comments beneath, but also adding it here for further trouble-shooting if it helps.

This is what my path shows: 
    "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/name_withheld/.rvm/bin"

Comment: Seems the XCode is not installed. Is it? If not, try again after installing it.

Comment: Also install the cli tools (not sure how it's called). Or some gcc

Comment: problem is that aside from going to another location where the default CDs that came with the laptop (installed xcode from that earlier). anyway, am at a different location and would like to solve this online if i can. for example the command line for xcode which is supposedly free, isn't. and everyone seems to say it is. Link: http://kennethreitz.com/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew.html - says all i need is a apple id - but when i do try to register - it asks me to which license i want and they all cost!

Comment: by gcc, you mean this one:https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer?

Comment: @oyvey I registered with my apple id and all went fine. Also if you have Xcode installed you can install the command line or whatever it's called inside it. Open Xcode, Preferences, Downloads, Components, Command Line Tools -> install

Comment: well ... not sure if it has to do with the version of Xcode (3.2.6) that I have but I don't see Downloads and onwards after going to Preferences. And as for apple id, they do require credit card -at least for me.

Comment: ok ... went through apple registration ... seems i may not be charged after all. but the most recent version of xcode that they have for free is only meant for mountain lion and lion. i'm on snow leopard.

Comment: then try to install gcc. If you have homebrew do `brew doctor`, it should tell you how to install gcc if you have none

Comment: the good news is that xcode seems to be installed. the bad news is that a simple command such as "rails new demo_app" doesn't create demo_app but rather new. and when it created it, i don't see bundle at the end of it.

Comment: If it creates `new` instead of `demo_app` it means you have Rails 2 instead of Rails 3. Try running `gem rails update`.

Comment: @Mischa this is what it comes up with: "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command rails
" this is so weird. i think i also have problems with rvm. but not sure how to fix it. sigh.

Comment: @ismaelga, i installed homebrew a long time ago, and was rather confused by it. so have been using rvm since then.

Comment: i think the apple store staff must have reset my laptop. it's the only thing that makes sense. but i don't understand how. because all my content is still here. so, how did it leave my content alone, and yet affect the settings for rvm, etc?

Comment: if it helps to troubleshoot this further: this is what i have in my path: "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/name_withheld/.rvm/bin" (going to add this to the post as well for easier reading.

Comment: hey @Mischa, thank you for your patience and repeatedly answering my questions. Merci.

Comment: hey @ismaelga, thank you for your patience and repeatedly answering my questions. Merci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also make sure you have Rails 3.x (ideally at least 3.2.y)...  You can check which Rails you are running by doing:

```
$ rails -v
```

Use:

```
$ gem install rails
```

to get the latest version of Rails.  Once you do a 'rails -v' and know you're running Rails 3, then a 'rails new foo' should create an app (and directory) called foo.

Also, Mischa had a typo, the command is:

```
$ gem update rails  # *Not* gem rails update ...
```

I would also run the following to 'start over' with rvm:

```
$ rvm implode
```

Then reinstall rvm, per the instructions [here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/).

You may also find this much easier: http://railsinstaller.org/#osx

Btw, homebrew and rvm are two totally separate things.  brew is used to download, build (compile), and install packages using a local (on your Mac) compiler (gcc or CLI tools, put there via Xcode or the Kenneth Reitz gcc installer).  rvm is Ruby Version Manager, it's only used to manage the different Ruby versions you might install.  To use it, you just say 'rvm 1.9.3' (assuming you've installed Ruby 1.9.3 already) to make sure you're using that version of ruby.

Similar to Rails, you can check which version of Ruby you're using by doing:

```
$ ruby -v
```

Also, rvm will tell you which one you're using (if it says 'system' then try the 'rvm 1.9.3' or 'rvm 1.9.2' command to change the one you're using):

```
$ rvm list
```

The one in use will have a '=*' or '=>' next to the one you're using (if you have a fairly recent version of rvm installed).

Good luck--let me know if any of this helps.

Comment: well ... ruby's version is 1.9.3 and rails version is 3.2.8. RVM's version is 1.15.8. Yet whenever I try to run "user$ type rvm | head -n 1" as per this page: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/, I get command not found. What does this mean? I've also tried to run this: "user$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" and I get "command not found" too. Any advice?

Comment: nvm! did this again "type rvm | head -1" and it worked. upon closer inspection, it's b/c I added user$ earlier when i shouldn't have. anyway, it's working, functional, and i can go back to following the tutorial again, i hope! yay! thank you. your answer pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: oh crap! i just realized that i have to go through keys verification again for github and heroku based on today's experience, right? Darn! Double darn! Oh well, will save it for another day.